# How can I parse List<List> into ArrayList<HashMap> through lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

Maybe it's quite a stupid question but I cant find any solution for it. I am new to lambda and I am trying to use it to parse a list `<List>` into an ArrayList `<HashMap>`.

Initially I parse a data set from csv file, and I turn each row of them into a List, and add them into the List <'List'> I stated above. Since I have to filter them after this, I would like to change the each row of them into a `HashMap<columnName, columnValue>`, but when I try to do it, it returns nothing.

Here is my code:

```
// import data from csv file
private static List<List> readWholeFile(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    List<List> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = br.readLine();

    try {
        if (line != null) {
            String[] test = line.split(",");
            List<String> row = Arrays.asList((String[]) line.split(","));
            rows.add(row);
            return readWholeFile(br);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return rows;
    }
}

//parse List<List> into ArrayList<HashMap>
private static ArrayList<HashMap> putRowIntoMap(List<List> rows, List<String> columns) {
    ArrayList<HashMap> itemMap = new ArrayList<>();
    List<HashMap> test = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> eleMap = new HashMap<>();
    rows.stream().map(row -> (row.stream().map(ele -> eleMap.put(keys.get(row.indexOf(ele)), (String) ele))))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    itemMap.add(eleMap);
    System.out.println(eleMap);  //output: {}

    return itemMap;
}
```

Comment: Please read: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: You use overcomplicated _recursive_ solution (instead of a plain loop) when reading a list which is not populated properly as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the input file into `List<List<String>>` using NIO `Files.lines` returning lines of the text file as `Stream<String>`

```java
public static List<List<String>> readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)) // Stream<String>
        .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(","))) // Stream<List<String>>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());               // List<List<String>>
}
```

2. Convert the list of `List<String>` into map, assuming that the `columnNames` have the same indexes as the lists inside `rows` and all column names are different.

```java
public static List<Map<String, String>> intoMap(List<List<String>> rows, List<String> columnNames) {
    return rows.stream() // Stream<List<String>>
        .map(row -> IntStream.range(0, row.size()) // IntStream
            .boxed() // Stream<Integer>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                i -> columnNames.get(i), // key: columnName
                i -> row.get(i)          // value
                // ,(r1, r2) -> r1,       // placeholder for merge function
                // LinkedHashMap::new    // supplier of LinkedHashMap
            )) // Map<String, String>
        ) // List<Map<String, String>>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

By default, `Collectors.toMap` returns a `HashMap` implementation which is not ordered, so it could make sense to use `LinkedHashMap` maintaining insertion order (if needed, two commented lines in the `toMap` should be uncommented).

Comment: not working for the intoMap, it shows "method collect in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Supplier<R>,ObjIntConsumer<R>,BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: Collector<Object,CAP#1,Map<Object,Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"

Comment: Added missing `.boxed()`, to convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`. it works now

Comment: it works now, thanks!!